# Why does __get ignore the echo before return when invalid?

Tags: php, function, methods

In the following example

```
class Employee
{
    var $name;
    var $city;
    protected $wage;
    function __get($propName)
    {
        echo "__get called!<br />";
        $vars = array("name","city");
        if (in_array($propName, $vars))
        {
            return $this->$propName;
        } else {
            return "No such variable!";
        }
    }
}
$employee = new Employee();
$employee->name = "Mario";
echo $employee->name."<br />";
echo $employee->age;
```

The output is:

```
Mario
__get called!
No such variable!
```

... confuses me, I understand that "__get called!" appears when $employee->name is accesed, but why does it not appear even when $employee->age is accesed? I mean... it's there but it seems like the __get considers only the return in the if-else statement. How is that possible?

Observation : Of course __get runs when it detects $age does not exist when read, but ...when it does run, why doesn't the echo in it work?

Conclusion: the "__get called!" appeared because of one call of __get, that in which $employee->age is read.

Comment: It does work.  When you see "__get called!", that is being echoed because you are accessing an inaccessible property (`age`).  `$name` is a publicly accessible property, which is why `__get()` is never even called on that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumptions are wrong.

> I understand that "__get called!" appears when $employee->name is accesed

No, it doesn't. `__get` is only invoked when you attempt to access a member which *does not exist*. You have defined a publicly accessible member named `$name`, this is what the line `var $name` does. Reading/writing to `$employee->name` will *never* invoke the magic `__get` or `__set_` methods.

It is not `$employee->name` that is causing `"__get called"` to be printed; `$employee->name` is returning `"Mario"`, the value you assigned to that member, and *that* is what is being printed. It is `$employee->age` that is causing `"__get called"` to be printed.

I've tried to better explain the lines and what they do in respect to `__get`:

```
$employee = new Employee();
$employee->name = "Mario";      # assign to $name
echo $employee->name."<br />";  # read "Mario" from $name, does NOT invoke  __get
echo $employee->age;            # attempt to read $age, invokes __get
```

RE: Your observation

> Observation : Of course __get runs when it detects $age does not exist when read, but ...when it does run, why doesn't the echo in it work?

The echo *does* work. The reason you are only seeing one `"__get called!"` is because `__get` is only called once, by attempting to access `$employee->age`.

Answer (score 2):

`__get()` is not called when you access properties of your object. It's run when you read `$employee->age` (which is not an existing property of your object)

Answer (score 2):

`$name` is a property of `$employee`, so `__get` isn't called for it: the property is directly read.

So, `__get` is being called once: for `age`.

Comment: @AndrewG.H. I've updated my answer to clarify. The echo runs every time `__get` is called - which is one time.